# CMake generator expression is not being evaluated

Tags: cmake

Due to the following warning:

```
CMake Error at test/CMakeLists.txt:29 (get_target_property):
  The LOCATION property may not be read from target "my_exe".  Use the
  target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.
```

which is the result from lines like this:

```
get_target_property(my_exe_path my_exe LOCATION)
```

Like recommended in the docs, I tried to use a generator expression like this:

```
add_executable(my_exe_path main.cpp)
message("path to executable: $<TARGET_FILE:my_exe_path>")
```

But `TARGET_FILE` is not being evaluated

```
path to executable: $<TARGET_FILE:my_exe>
```

I'm using CMake 3.4 and added `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)` to my `CMakeLists.txt` so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm on Linux using command line build and QtCreator (CodeBlocks) generator. I started printing the evaluated expression using `message()` when `add_test(test1 $<TARGET_FILE:my_exe>)` didn't work. So I guessed the expression was not evaluated correctly (and I still do).

Comment: Hey, why do you just comment when you actually know the answer? Your hint was very helpful (actually I even forgot to add `enable_testing()` which prevented the tests from being run, too :). Can you turn *both* comments into an answer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While generator expression is stored at *configuration* stage (when corresponded CMake command is executed),
*evaluation* of generator expressions is performed at **build stage**.

This is why `message()` command prints generator expression in non-dereferenced form: value denoted by the generator expression **is not known at this stage**.

Moreover, CMake never dereferences generator expressions by itself. Instead, it generates appropriate string in the build file, which is then interpreted by *build utility* (`make`, `Visual Studio`, etc.).

Note, that **not every** CMake **command accepts** *generator expressions*. Each possible usage of *generator expressions* is *explicitely* described in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/cmake-commands.7.html) for specific command. Moreover, different CMake *command flows* or *different options* have *different policy* about using of *generator expressions*.

For example, command flow

```
add_test(NAME <name> COMMAND <executable>)
```

*accepts* generator expressions for `COMMAND` option,

but command flow

```
add_test(<name> <executable>)
```

doesn't!

Another example of policies difference:

```
install(DIRECTORY <dir> DESTINATION <dest>)
```

In this command flow generator expressions are allowed for `DESTINATION`, but not for `DIRECTORY` option.

Again, **read documentation carefully**.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a quick and easy way to print the value of a generator expression:

```
add_custom_target(print
        ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo $<1:hello> $<0:world>
    )
```

In this example, if you run `cmake .` and then `make print`, you will see "hello" (without the quotation marks) in the output.

However, if you just use `message($<1:hello> $<0:world>)`, you will see "`$<1:hello> $<0:world>`" as output (again, without the quotation marks).

Comment: Actually, didn't work for me... Where would this print? I don't see it in neither in compiler output nor in the CMake output. I've tried with cmake 3.10 and 3.12...

Comment: @GregKramida It adds a target. You need to run or build the target