# Ternary generator expression not evaluating

Tags: cmake

Suppose I have an option:

```cmake
option(TARGET_IS_ADDIN "Shared library target is an Addin" ON)
```

and a variable:

```cmake
set(MyVar $<IF:$<BOOL:${TARGET_IS_ADDIN}>,addin,script>)
```

why is this getting stored as:

```cmake
"$<IF:$<BOOL:ON>,addin,script>"
```

and not `"addin"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the value for your option `TARGET_IS_ADDIN` is expanded at CMake's **configuration** stage, generator expressions are evaluated at CMake's buildsystem **generation** stage. Thus, when you attempt to print a generator expression using `message()`, you will see its un-expanded form, as the generation stage has not yet taken place.

Furthermore, not all of CMake's commands even accept generator expressions. The [`set()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html) command is **not** one that can process generator expressions because it is processed at the configuration stage. If a command can process generator expressions, it will be *explicitly* mentioned in *that* command's documentation (e.g. [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) or [`target_compile_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html)).

For examples, see Tsyvarev's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35697020).

Comment: This was actual a variable referenced in the input file in `configure_file()`. Is it possible to use a the expression in some way in place of the variable name?

Comment: That's happening at generation stage right? Since the input file is being modified and sent to the `PROJECT_BINARY_DIR`.

Comment: @Sean McVeigh No, `configure_file()` (as its name conveniently suggests) also occurs at *configure* time. If you want to change the value being passed to `configure_file()`, I suggest just using an [`if`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/command/if.html)-statement based on the value of your option.